# Issue with SerieCollection(1).Point(2) "parameter invalid" for a Pie Chart

Tags: excel, vba, charts, pie-chart

I have an issue on the last line for Points(2), but not for Points(1). It states "parameter invalid".
The code I found use the property Points, but I couldn't get any information online (Microsoft doc) about this property linked to SerieCollection.

Note this code is working sometimes. If I click a button to create another chart (Line chart), then the click on another button to create the pie chart below works! (Before this code I erase the previous Line chart)

```
' Create a Chart
Dim myPieChart1 As Shape
Set myPieChart1 = Sheet1.Shapes.AddChart2
myPieChart1.Name = "ProjectPercent"
' Chart size
myPieChart1.Chart.ChartArea.Left = 200
myPieChart1.Chart.ChartArea.Top = 180
myPieChart1.Chart.ChartArea.Width = 240
myPieChart1.Chart.ChartArea.Height = 240
myPieChart1.Chart.ChartArea.RoundedCorners = True
myPieChart1.Chart.ChartArea.Interior.Color = RGB(32, 55, 100)
' Pie Chart characteristic
myPieChart1.Chart.ChartType = xlPie
myPieChart1.Chart.SetSourceData Sheet1.Range("$G$10:$H$12")
myPieChart1.Chart.HasTitle = True
myPieChart1.Chart.ChartTitle.Caption = "Project Activity"
myPieChart1.Chart.ChartTitle.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
myPieChart1.Chart.HasLegend = True
myPieChart1.Chart.Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionTop
myPieChart1.Chart.Legend.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
' Chart labels
myPieChart1.Chart.ApplyDataLabels xlDataLabelsShowPercent
myPieChart1.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
myPieChart1.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Position = xlLabelPositionBestFit
myPieChart1.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Font.ColorIndex = 25
myPieChart1.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Font.Size = 12
' Pie Chart colors
myPieChart1.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(1).Interior.Color = RGB(198, 239, 206)
myPieChart1.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206)
```

I added the line: myPieChart1.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries, but it didn't help.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See below.  Apply the variable and you will see the relevant intellisense.

The way you wrote is inappropriate for chart points.

```
myPieChart1.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(1).Interior.Color = RGB(198, 239, 206)
```

### Edited

I modified the code for your chart.

```
Sub creatChart()

    
    ' Create a Chart
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim myPieChart1 As Shape
    Dim Cht As Chart
    Dim Srs As Series
    Dim pnt As Point
    Dim Lbl As DataLabels
    
    Set Ws = Sheets(1)
    Set myPieChart1 = Ws.Shapes.AddChart2
    myPieChart1.Name = "ProjectPercent"
    ' Chart size
    Set Cht = myPieChart1.Chart
        
    With Cht
        With .ChartArea
            .Left = 200
            .Top = 180
            .Width = 240
            .Height = 240
            .RoundedCorners = True
            .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(32, 55, 100)
        End With
        .ChartType = xlPie
        .SetSourceData Ws.Range("$G$10:$H$12")
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Caption = "Project Activity"
        .ChartTitle.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        .HasLegend = True
        .Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionTop
        .Legend.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        '.ApplyDataLabels xlDataLabelsShowLabelAndPercent
        
        Set Srs = .SeriesCollection(1)
        With Srs
            .ApplyDataLabels xlDataLabelsShowLabelAndPercent
            Set Lbl = .DataLabels
            '.DataLabels.Position = xlLabelPositionBestFit
            Set Lbl = .DataLabels
            With Lbl
                .Position = xlLabelPositionBestFit
                .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(32, 55, 100)
                .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 12
            End With
                
            Set pnt = .Points(1)
                pnt.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(198, 239, 206)
            Set pnt = .Points(2)
                pnt.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 199, 206)
        End With
    End With
        
End Sub
```

[image]

### sample

```
Sub test1()
    Dim Cht As Chart
    Dim objCht As ChartObject
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Srs As Series
    Dim pnt As Point
    
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    Set objCht = Ws.ChartObjects(1)
    Set Cht = objCht.Chart
    
    With Cht
        Set Srs = .SeriesCollection(1)
        With Srs
            Set pnt = .Points(2)
            pnt.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(100, 0, 0)
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, I already tried "Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB" instead of "Interior.Color" (found online), but without success. When I applied your code, I got an error: Method ChartObjects_Worksheet failed. But, your start is also quite different than mine, because I used 'Shapes.AddChart2'. There is something I don't understand, because I am pretty sure your code is good.

Comment: Sorry, but it is still not working with the same error "Parameter not valid" on line Set pnt = .Points(2). Why is it working with you and not with me? It is a mystery! Is it something missing in the Reference? But I think Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library should be enough. Note also, I can make it work (my original code) when I click another button which create a Line chart, then my button which create this Pie chart and also delete the previous Line chart. Mystery again!